# T-SQL previous year total in next year column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

I currently have a table that looks like this:

```
fscYear ID          Days    #Invoices     AVG
2011    20000807    221     7             27
2012    20000807    403     15            25
2013    20000807    390     14            26
2014    20000807    119     4             23
```

I would like to include the previous year's AVG in the next year, like so:

```
fscYear ID          Days    #Invoices   AVG  prevAVG
2011    20000807    221     7           27    0
2012    20000807    403     15          25    27
2013    20000807    390     14          26    25
2014    20000807    119     4           23    26
```

How I can achieve that?

*edit* the SQL is straightforward,

```
select * from theTableThatHoldsThedata
```

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: SQL 2008 R2 and SQL 2012

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write as:

```
SELECT Cur.fscYear ,Cur.ID,Cur.Days,Cur.#Invoices,Cur.AVG,  
       isnull(Prv.AVG,0) AS prevAVG
FROM test  AS Cur
LEFT OUTER JOIN test AS Prv
ON Cur.fscYear = Prv.fscYear + 1;
```

<kbd>[Demo](http://rextester.com/YMU79580)</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

Most databases support ANSI standard window functions.  You can do this with `lag()`:

```
select t.*, coalesce(lag(avg) over (order by by fscyear), 0) as prevAVG
from atable t;
```

This will work in SQL Server 2012+.  For earlier versions, you can use a correlated subquery or `apply`:

```
select t.*, coalesce(tprev.prevAvg, 0) as prevAvg
from atable t outer apply
     (select top 1 t2.Avg as prevAvg
      from atable t2
      where t2.fscyear < t.fscyear
      order by t2.fscyear desc
     ) tprev;
```

Comment: The first solution gives me this error: The Parallel Data Warehouse (PDW) features are not enabled. I don't think I'd be able to enable that on a live system. Testing the 2nd solution now

Comment: The 2nd solution throws away the 2011 record and repeats the number 27 for all other years

Comment: @user3036342 . . . I left out the `order by`.

Comment: Your 2nd suggestion/edit works, but it still throws away the first record, 2011.

Comment: @user3036342 change `cross apply` to `Outer Apply` as the first record or the smallest year won't satisfy the where condition.